# xcode 10.1 is not installed on my mac although there are 18 GB free

Tags: xcode

I can not install xcode 10.1 on my mac 
it gives me error

There is not enough disk space available to install the product.

although I have 18 GB free

can anyone tell me what is the problem

Comment: I have the same issue with XCode 10.2.1. I have 54 GB free on my mac.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64086816/2273080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xcode xip file is around 6GB. When you unzip it, it will take around 12 GB of space. Further installation will take place once you launch the xcode first time. So yes 18GB seems a lot but xcode can eat it all in no time and want more.

Comment: I was using xcode 10 , but it keeps asking for update and it keep downloading the update for days and it does not update , and now I removed it all and try to get a fresh copy but it still refuse to install , is there any way to download the xip and install it in another data volume ?

Comment: You can install it in any volume you want. Just unxip the xcode file in that volume.

Answer (score 3):

Clear the data from these two locations on your mac book

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

These are temp files. They will be regenerated by Xcode.

Now try installing.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with AppStore, I had the same issue I had to download the file directly

here is the link for Xcode 10.2
https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.2/Xcode_10.2.xip

here my alternative link from google drive
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1obcFEhddXF9cCMviSiA144r9ymDzNHhv&export=download

just download and installed

Answer (score 0):

⦿ if you have enough space and still facing this issue, you may need to **Restart Your Mac**.

⦿ And if you want to clear some space, you need to remove these folders:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```