# Xcode 11.2 not updating

Tags: xcode, macos, installation, macos-mojave

### show disk space not enough

[image: show disk space not enough]

I’m using macOS Mojave 10.14.5

I have 11.69GB free disk space

when I click the install  it's always show alert message "We could not complete your update, there is not enough disk space available to install the product".

How to fix the problem ? please help

Comment: Facing the same issue!

Answer (score 2):

**For the Latest Version of XCode 12 you need to have a minimum of 40 GB of free space before updating or downloading Xcode**

If you have other issues with memory you can try @vedRanuiar Answer to get some free space.

Answer (score 1):

I have more free space than you and couldn't update my already installed Xcode 11.1 to 11.2. 
What I did was to manually download the file. You search for the version you want by going here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Or here's the direct link to the Xcode 11.2 download file you're looking for:
https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11.2/Xcode_11.2.xip

Comment: I had problems even with Catalina 10.15.1, so if anybody still has problems updating Xcode with the latest macOS, the above solution works.

Answer (score 1):

It needs almost 18GB when installed, so before installation make sure you have at least 20GB of free space

Comment: I have 20GB space and I can't install too

Comment: I have 36GB and couldn't either

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem and this is how I solved it:
I suggest you have an external hard drive. Then download a desired version of the xcode to this page.[download](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)

If a XIP file is located on your desktop: open the “Terminal” application found in /Applications/Utilities/ and run the following command:

> xip -x ~/Desktop/Xcode_8.2.1.xip

Then wait until it has finished installing

Comment: this answer should have been accepted. I use this successfully for my Xcode_12.4. thnx

Answer (score 0):

### i have found my problem it's technical issues.

Finally able to getting Xcode 11.2 installed after updating the Mojave 10.14.5 to macOS Catalina 10.15.1.

[image]

- ## [Catalina 10.15.1 requirements](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201475)
- MacBook introduced in 2015 or later
- MacBook Air introduced in 2012 or later
- MacBook Pro introduced in 2012 or later
- Mac mini introduced in 2012 or later
- iMac introduced in 2012 or later
- iMac Pro (all models)
- Mac Pro introduced in 2013 or later

Answer (score 0):

Just clean both directories and reclaim 16-30 GB of Hard Drive Space From Xcode -

- `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` - It is safe to delete directories here.
- `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/` - A folder for each combination of iOS devices you have plugged in.